# Mockito when statement not triggering during Spring Boot REST Controller Test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-restcontroller, spring-test-mvc

I've written a typical three layer Spring Boot REST API and am building out the tests for it. The API itself works fine but I am running into issues getting the controller tests to work. The body that's being returned is empty because the object the controller layer is getting back is null. Here are the main dependencies in play.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.12.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>  

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I've mocked out the service layer but the when statement in the test doesn't seem to be firing as I'd expect.

Here's the test itself:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class VehicleControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    VehicleServiceImpl vService;

    @Mock
    HttpServletRequest mockRequest;

    @Mock
    Principal mockPrincipal;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    Vehicle vehicle1;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws ItemNotFoundException {

        vehicle1 = new Vehicle();
        vehicle1.setVin("5YJ3E1EA5KF328931");
        vehicle1.setColor("black");
        vehicle1.setDisplayName("Black Car");
        vehicle1.setId(1L);
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser("USER")
    public void findVehicleByIdSuccess() throws Exception {

        //Given **I think the problem is here***
        when(vService.findVehicleById(any(),any(),any())).thenReturn(vehicle1);

        //When
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/vehicles/1")).andDo(print())

        //Then
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Here's the corresponding controller method:

```
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
public class VehicleController {


    @JsonView(VehicleView.summary.class)
    @GetMapping("/vehicles/{id}")
    public Vehicle findVehicleById(@PathVariable Long id, Principal principal,
                                   HttpServletRequest request) throws ItemNotFoundException {

        log.info("In controller " +LogFormat.urlLogFormat(request,principal.getName()));       
        return vehicleService.findVehicleById(id,principal, request);
     }
```

Here's the MockHTTPServletResponse. It has a status of 200 but the body is empty

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

For reference here's the service method that I'm trying to Mock

```
    @Override
    public Vehicle findVehicleById(Long id, Principal principal, HttpServletRequest request) throws ItemNotFoundException {

        Optional<Vehicle> vehicle = vehicleRepository.findByIdAndUserId(id,principal.getName());     

        if (vehicle.isPresent()){
            return vehicle.get();
        } else {
            throw new ItemNotFoundException(id,"vehicle");
        }
    }
```

I've tried different versions of Springboot but that hasn't helped. I had started off using 2.2.4 but I figured I would try the 2.1.X train since it has been around longer. I can confirm the correct method in the controller is being called because of the log output I'm getting.

Comment: Place a breakpoint in findVehicleById of controller and check what is the actual class of vechicleService injected is it really the same mock that you've declared in a test class (both the type and the instance)?

Comment: Your `@Mock` for the `Principal` and `HttpServletRequest` are useless, remove them. Instead of `any()` for the `Principal` parameter try `nullable(Principal.class)`. There has been a change in Mockito and `any()` doesn't match `null` arguments anymore. Regarding your optional use don't use `if` as that beats t he purpose of an option instead write `return vehicle.orElseThrow(() -> new ItemNotFoundException(id,"vehicle"));` which is how you should use it.

Comment: Thank you for everyone's comments. I took a look at the debugger and was able to confirm that the controller is indeed using the mocked `vehicleService`. I also tried the suggestion to use `nullable(Principle.class)` but to no avail. Since Spring security is part of the test I believe I need to be able to match on the `Principal` it's using which in my case has a username of `USER`.  I'm going to keep fiddling around with the matchers to see if I can get something to work.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing the following line:

```
when(vService.findVehicleById(any(),any(),any())).thenReturn(vehicle1);
```

with this (explicitity provide the class in `any()`):

```
when(vService.findVehicleById(any(Long.class),any(Principal.class),any(HttpServletRequest.class))).thenReturn(vehicle1);
```

Ignore the following part, as @M. Deinum pointed out that `@MockBean` does inject the mock object so this is irrelevant.

---

You did mock your service object but you didn't inject it into your controller.

```
@InjectMocks
private VehicleController vehicleController = new VehicleController();
```

Initialize these mock objects using `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` and instead of autowiring `MockMvc` object try to pass your controller in it like this:

```
@BeforeEach
void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(vehicleController).build();
```

Comment: Spring Boot takes care of that using the `@MockBean` annotation.

Comment: I tried the suggestion of matching on `any(thing.class)` but I got the same result. I also tried moving the `when` statement into the `setUp()` method without success. For grins I changed `@BeforeEach` to `@BeforeAll` with the same result. Also tried `given` instead of `when`, no luck either